# Find latest AWS API version for locking the version

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

AWS themselves mention that it's important to lock the API version you use to prevent any unexpected changes to API from breaking your code (see [Locking API Versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/locking-api-versions.html)).

However, I can't seem to find the latest API version for AWS Lambda. I want to pass this to AWS Boto3 ([docs here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client)). Where do I find the latest API version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you referenced says:

> **Getting API Versions**
>   To get the API version for a service, see the Locking the API Version section on the service's reference page, such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html for Amazon S3.

Therefore, the API version for Lambda can be found on:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks John. However, that's for JS. As described in the question, I'm looking for the API version for Python's Boto3. I can't find it in the docs (link in my question).

Comment: The API Version displayed is for the _service_, not the _SDK_. That's why it is showing Lambda as 2015, since all Lambda API changes since then have been forward-compatible. (And, I can tell you, the SDK has _certainly_ been updated since then.)

Comment: I see, thanks! I was confused by the website having `AWSJavaScriptSDK` in the URL.

Comment: Le sigh – AWS appears to be, as is sadly very common, not that great at maintaining docs. Apparently all of the links, even given "/latest/", are out of date, and it's still not clear to me how to find the various versions of the AWS RDS API.

Comment: You can see a list of API versions inside the botocore code here: https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/master/botocore/data

Answer (score 3):

AWS's docs are *terrible* about including info for previous versions, or even what versions exist, or at least it sure seems that way for the AWS RDS API anyways.

This site seems to be the best way to find info about versions of the different AWS APIs:

- [AWS API Changes](https://awsapichanges.info/)

Sadly, that site's home page doesn't seem to include anyway to filter for a specific service.

Thankfully, it does seem like you can do it 'manually':

1. Open [AWS API Changes](https://awsapichanges.info/) in your browser.
2. Perform an in-page search (via your browser) for the relevant service, e.g. "RDS".
3. Click on the header for any 'changes entry' for the relevant service. [[Here](https://awsapichanges.info/archive/changes/078bdc-rds.html) is an example change entry for RDS.]
4. On the changes entry details page, there should be 'breadcrumb' links at the top, ex. "API Changes / Services / Amazon Relational Database Service  / 2021-09-10".
5. Click the breadcrumb link for the service, e.g. "Amazon Relational Database Service".

Example for RDS API changes:

- [Amazon Relational Database Service – AWS API Changes](https://awsapichanges.info/archive/changes/078bdc-rds.html)